# Move files to its corresponding folders

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

How can I move every file to its corresponding folder?
I managed to create a folder depending on the title of the file. Now I want to move every file to its folder.

My code:

```
import os 
directorio=list(os.listdir())

pdfs=[]

for i in directorio: 
  if i.endswith('.pdf'):
    pdfs.append(i)
  
#with this step we create different folders for each group of files 
for i in range(len(pdfs)):

  folder=pdfs[i].split('#')[1].split('.')[0]

  try:
    folder=os.mkdir(folder)
  except:
    pass
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaned up version of your original code which moves as well.  Note that I have used `pathlib.Path` rather than the old `os.path` api.

```py
from pathlib import Path

for pdf in Path(".").glob("*.pdf"):
    dir = pdf.parent / pdf.stem.split("#")[-1]
    dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    pdf.rename(dir / pdf.name)
```

Changes:

- use glob.  But listdir and manual filtering also works
- don't cast to list
- move straight after making the dir, since that's what we want the dir for, and we know it at the moment!

`exist_ok` causes mkdir to continue if the directory is already present, rather than throwing an error.

Comment: Wow! super efficient and straightforward way to do the same. Thanks!